# If a SwingWorker task is canceled how do I know when interrupted method completed

Tags: java, swingworker

If a `SwingWorker` task is canceled, how do I know when the interrupted method completed.

I have simplified the code. `FixSongsController.start()` runs in the background. When it completes, a report is created and when that is done the report is then displayed using the `done()` method.

There is a progress dialog running and if the user elects to cancel ( whilst `FixSongsController.start()` is running ), this then invokes `cancel(true)` on the `SwingWorker` causing an interrupt to be sent to `FixSongsController.start()`. The trouble is, as soon as it's sent, it then invokes `createReport().`

**I don't want to to start creating the report until `FixSongsController.start()` has actually finished. I can't see how to identify when that has occurred.**

If I remove the `createReport` code from `FixSongsDialog` and the `isCancelled()` checks on Fix Songs the problem is worse because then `FixSongsDialog` trys to display the report before it has been created.

I thought I could make use of `SwingWorker.getState()` but once `cancelTask` is invoked `doInBackground()` task is interrupted and completes shortly after even though `FixSongsController` method is still tidying up.

Then I thought I could use `SwingWorker.setProgress()` within `FixSongsController.start()` method in its `finally` block and add a listener that would only invoke `showReport` once the progress value had changed but `setProgress` is protected so I cannot access it outside of `FixSongs` class itself.

`SwingWorker` Class

```
public class FixSongs extends SwingWorker<String, Object>
    {
        @Override
        public String doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
            try
            {
                new FixSongsController().start();
                if (!isCancelled())
                {
                    new FixSongsReportCreator().createReport();
                }
                return "";
            }
            catch (Throwable ex)
            {
                MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done()
        {
            SongKong.mainWindow.dialog.close();
            if (!isCancelled())
            {
                 ShowCounters showCounters = new ShowReport();
            }
        }
    }
```

Progress Dialog Class

```
public class FixSongsDialog extends RecordBasedProgressDialog
{
    ....


    @Override
    public void cancelTask()
    {
        try
        {
            swingWorker.cancel(true);
            CreateReport createReport = new CreateReport();
            createReport.execute();
            this.dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE,ex.getMessage(),ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    class CreateReport extends SwingWorker<String, Object>
    {
        @Override
        public String doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
            try
            {
                new FixSongsReportCreator().createReport();
                return "";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE,ex.getMessage(),ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done()
        {
            ShowCounters showCounters = new ShowReport();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if I understand your question correctly, but maybe you need to use join here ? Try this: FixSongsController fsc = new FixSongsController(); fsc.start(); fsc.join()

Comment: can you also post what happens on FixSongsReportCreator class createReport method ?